Some apps in terminal emulator select tabs as spaces, yet others behave as expected
Task
I need to copy/paste text containing tab characters between various different remote servers as well as my own host system, between different apps as well, both text-based and graphical.  To keep things simple, however, I'll only be using my host system for this question.
Environment
GNOME 44.9
GNOME Terminal 3.50.1 (Also tested: Terminology 1.13.0, GNOME Console (kgx) 45.beta, XTerm 383)
VIM 9.1.16 (Also tested: GNU nano 7.2, more from util-linux 2.39.3, cat from GNU coreutils 9.1)
Input
A plain text file containing tab characters/tabs (UTF-8: 0x09).
Problem
Opening the input file using VIM within GNOME Terminal, for example, and selecting text containing tabs, the tabs are selected as individual spaces.  Visual example of SSH config file in VIM:

Here, I selected the first two lines and stopped in between the tab character on the third line, in the same place as the "t" in the first line (not using VIM's visual mode, this is the standard selection within GNOME Terminal).  Normally, this should not be allowed; depending on where the mouse cursor is, either none of the tab character is selected, or the entire tab character up to the letter "U" is selected, nothing in between.  The selection is subsequently copied and pasted as individual spaces.
However, the tabs are displayed correctly in VIM, not converted to spaces, the cursor moves from one end of the tab to the other, and so on, as expected.  Hexdump with tabs highlighted (they are there!):
00000000  48 6f 73 74 20 73 75 70  65 72 75 73 65 72 0a 09  |Host superuser..|
00000010  48 6f 73 74 6e 61 6d 65  20 73 75 70 65 72 75 73  |Hostname superus|
00000020  65 72 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 09  55 73 65 72 20 72 6f 6f  |er.com..User roo|
00000030  74 0a 09 49 64 65 6e 74  69 74 79 46 69 6c 65 20  |t..IdentityFile |
00000040  7e 2f 2e 73 73 68 2f 73  75 70 65 72 75 73 65 72  |~/.ssh/superuser|
00000050  2e 72 6f 6f 74 0a                                 |.root.|
00000056
Expected Results
The expected behavior is observed with more, for example.  Visual example using more:

Here, I made the same selection as I did with VIM and stopped my mouse in the same spot as well, aligned with the "t" in the first line.  The tabs are selected as tabs and are subsequently copied and pasted as tabs.
Attempted Solutions
This doesn't appear to have anything to do with GNOME Terminal or its settings; I tested with the other emulators previously mentioned and got the same results.  Since the correct behavior is observed with different apps, it appears to be an app setting or bug.  I searched around and couldn't find anything relevant for nano.  For VIM, I tried different settings like smarttab, tabstop, expandtab, and so on, but the problem remained.  I also tried Visual mode, in which the expected behavior is observed.  Unfortunately, this only works within VIM; I can't "put" text "yanked" from VIM into gedit, for example, or any other app for that matter!
Questions
The questions that remain then, seem to apply to on a per-application basis.  I know most text editors have a setting to convert tabs to spaces, so when the tab key is pressed, 8 spaces are inputted instead.  In that case, a space character is in the actual file.  Therefore, it's expected that, when selected, it is selected as a space and subsequently copied and pasted as a space.
Here, this observation/problem is only affecting the selection of the text.  A tab character is in the actual file.  Yet, it can be selected as up to 8 individual spaces and subsequently copied and pasted as up to 8 individual spaces.  Maybe this behavior is desired by some in some instances?
Is this expected for VIM and nano?  If so, why?  Are there settings for these apps preventing them from selecting tabs as tabs, or settings to allow tabs to be selected as tabs?  Is there a term for this sort of mangling of text?
Are these rather bugs in VIM, nano, and perhaps other apps?

Research: printf 'A\tB\tC\n' > /tmp/tbs; more /tmp/tbs; tabs 5 8 20; more /tmp/tbs; tabs 3 18 22; more /tmp/tbs; tabs -8; more /tmp/tbs. I guess full-terminal editors like vim do not want to rely on these settings, so they may choose to print spaces to the terminal (and still edit and save the tabs you expect). Then your terminal emulator may treat tabs like sequences of spaces (konsole does, gnome-terminal doesn't) and this matters for copy-pasting. A terminal multiplexer (tmux or screen), if any, sits in between and it also may convert tabs to spaces.
